# Apache / Hosts file blocking unwanted connections

Tags: hosts

I have set up a local website on my machine running at port 80. I have also set up a list of unwanted connections in my host file (using this : http://www.putorius.net/2012/01/block-unwanted-advertisements-on.html).

All http requests to these websites are redirected to my local Apache :/. Is there any way to avoid having these requests processed by Apache?

BR/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid unwanted websites to be redirected to your local apache, you have two solutions :

- Change the IP of the unwanted websites in /etc/hosts to another IP than 127.0.0.1
- Make your local apache server listen on another TCP port than 80 (ie. 8080)